# Scrapy scrapes duplicates and ignores unique entries - changes with every run

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, duplicates, scrapy-splash

I'm working on a project to scrape Hoteldata ( Name, Id, Price,...) from Tripadvisor. My scraper seems to work: after the script is done my database is populated with 264 rows of data - just as many as there are results in Tripadvisor for properties in Copenhagen ( https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-oa240-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html ). However, on closer inspection I found out that I've got 26 duplicates in my data and that some hotel listings were not scraped. On further inspection I found out that with every run ( even right after each other) I got different duplicates, sometimes more sometimes less but the total amount of rows stayed the same thus some hotels appeared in one run but not in the other.

I made an excel spreadsheet with my latest runs. Each tab stores one run. The tabs are named after the military time of the run. I did one run yesterday ( called "yesterday") where I did not use the scrapy settings but just downloader_middleware from scrapy. No problems during the run but I still fixed it. I also increased Splash wait from 5 to 10 seconds today :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5e2wqdt94yrjdgv/Tripadvisor_Multiple_Duplicates.xlsx?dl=0
(sheet5 = 1301)

Hoteldata_spider.py

```
import scrapy
from ..items import HotelinfoItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class HoteldataSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Hoteldata"
    start_urls = ["http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https:"
                  "//www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand-Hotels.html"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 10})

    def parse(self, response):
        items = HotelinfoItem()

        all_single_entries = response.css("div.listItem")

        for entry in all_single_entries:
            hotel_names = entry.css(".listing_title [target=_blank]::text").extract()
            hotel_links = entry.css(".listing_title a").xpath("@href").extract()
            hotel_ids = entry.css(".listing_title").css("a::attr(id)").extract()
            hotel_displayed_price = entry.css(".premium_offer_container").css("div::attr(data-pernight)").extract()
            hotel_type = entry.css(".mb10").css(".label::text").extract()


            items["hotel_names"] = [str(hotel_names).split("'")[1]]
            items["hotel_links"] = ["https://www.tripadvisor.com" + str(hotel_links).split("'")[1]]
            items["hotel_ids"] = [str(hotel_ids).split("_")[1].split("'")[0]]

            if len(hotel_type) == 0:
                items["hotel_type"] = ["Hotel"]
            else:
                items["hotel_type"] = hotel_type

            if len(hotel_displayed_price) == 0:
                items["hotel_displayed_price"] = ["NA"]
            else:
                items["hotel_displayed_price"] = hotel_displayed_price

            yield items

        next_page = response.css("a.next::attr(href)").get()
        next_page_splash = "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.tripadvisor.com" + \
                           str(next_page).split("#")[0] + "&timeout=10&wait=5"

        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page_splash, callback=self.parse)
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class HotelinfoItem(scrapy.Item):
    hotel_names = scrapy.Field()
    hotel_ids = scrapy.Field()
    hotel_links = scrapy.Field()
    hotel_displayed_price = scrapy.Field()
    hotel_type = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
import mysql.connector
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['hotel_ids'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %r" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter['hotel_ids'])
            return item

    
class HotelinfoPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="root",
            passwd="****",
            database="hotel_links"
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hotel_links_with_prices_tb""")
        self.curr.execute(""" CREATE TABLE hotel_links_with_prices_tb (
                        hotel_names text,
                        hotel_ids integer,
                        hotel_links text,
                        hotel_displayed_price text,
                        hotel_type text
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO hotel_links_with_prices_tb VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['hotel_names'][0],
            item['hotel_ids'][0],
            item['hotel_links'][0],
            item['hotel_displayed_price'][0],
            item['hotel_type'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'Hotelinfo'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['Hotelinfo.spiders'] NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Hotelinfo.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723, 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725, 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810, }
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = { 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100, }
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'Hotelinfo.pipelines.HotelinfoPipeline': 300, }
```

I left middlewares.py untouched.

I would be very grateful if someone had a hint on the solution of my problem. thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried using a duplicate pipeline which Scrapy docs gives you. Do you get the same output ? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter. Also it may be worth thinking about logging your spider to see what's happening. The scrapy log may be worth posting up (Pastebin might be an option if the log is quite long).

Comment: Hi @AaronS,

I'm not sure what logging is. I printed the output from my terminal to pastbin: https://pastebin.com/YKx2qDm9 

I looked at duplication couples and went on the links scrapy had used to pull the data from. To my surprise I found out that for instance when I entered  the url scrapy used for the first occurrence of "Zleep Hotel Copenhagen Area"  I couldn't find that hotel on the page. However when loading that url multiple times in different tabs I did sometimes get this Hotel as an entry. I then set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS =1  in settings.py but without much difference.

Comment: I tried duplicate pipeline but it didn't change anything. Perhaps I handled it in a wrong way. I just copied my duplication pipeline changes to my initial post in pipelines.py

Comment: Logging is a way of monitoring your scrape. Its a standard python lib, is quite flexible, so for example you could log when your links are scraped and how many times etc... I was interested to see if there was any log errors/critical. Which I couldn't find. The dropbox link you had isn't working now. Modifying the duplication pipeline shouldn't be too much effort just a small amount of editing, it's a way definitely make sure whatever you're getting isn't going to be a duplicate request. You want to figure out a way to do data validation.https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

Comment: thanks @AaronS ! I just fixed the Dropbox-link though I doubt it's still relevant. 

I asked the same question on reddit and there a user told me that the pages are independent from another and thus there isn't a clear run through all pages without duplicates since there's some randomness in where an entry appears. Would you confirm this ? 

Concerning the duplicatespipeline : I already modified the pipeline ( shown in initial posting ) I replaced "id" with "hotel_id". But I still got duplicates in my end result. I must have done something wrong I guess...

Comment: It doesn't look like you've put the duplicatepipline in the itempipeline your settings.py! Which is why it probably isn't working. The actual code for the dup is fine to me, as you said not much to change from the docs. In terms of randomness indeed this is correct about how scrapy deals with requests, the problem may be that the site pages are changing between runs of the scraper, so links that are appearing in scrapy but not on the website. Trying to atleast get a unique hit will hopefully be helped by a duplicate pipeline.